# Express App/Router as middleware

Tags: express

I was going through [app.use()](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) and found the following

> function can be a middleware function, a series of middleware functions, an array of middleware functions, or a combination of all of them. Since router and app implement the middleware interface, you can use them as you would any other middleware function.

I was not able to understand which scenario I will tend to use the app/router as my middleware in my express application And what will be it's impact?

**A more detailed Explanation**

I understand the middlewares in expressJS are like the filters/servlets in Java environment. That said the middlewares will be called one by one whenever any request comes to the server. Let's go by the following example:

```
var middleWare = function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
};

app.get('/hello', middleWare);
```

Now, how do the app/router fit as middle-wares.

*an express app as a middleware:*

```
var subApp = express();
subApp.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})
app.use(subApp);
```

*using router as a middleware:*

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})
app.use(router);
```

Now, I am not able to understand which scenario I will tend to use the app/router as a middleware in my express application And how will my application behave in this case, any impact?

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between sub-applications and routers is that the latter inherits the application configuration and creating a new express application doesn't.

You should use a sub-application only if you want two completely separated applications without settings inheritance.

More about it [here](http://www.therightcode.net/differences-between-express-3-and-express-4/).